# phalcon: Using devtools: How do I just add a controller and a view that works?

Tags: php, phalcon

I am starting to experiment with Phalcon because it looks promising.

I get index.php working. My controller `IndexController.php` and the corresponding view seem to be fine. But when I add a controller and a view, say `TestController` and `views/test/test.phtml` I get nothing.

I tried setting it all up with the developer tools rather than doing it by hand and ... still nothing.

Comment: What is your action. It should be `public function testAction()`. Otherwise check error logs from php / webserver to see what error PHP interpreter throws.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I started wwith just TestController containing indexAction(). I just added testAction() and then tested with: DOMAIN/test and DOMAIN/test/test. Both failed. I'm pretty stumped.

Comment: Turns out this wasn't a controller issue at all. I had to add "AllowOverride All" to my vhosts file.

Comment: Can you add that as the answer and accept it? twice I have come to this question to help ;)